# Django не видит файлы CSS, IMG, JS в static

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

столкнулся с проблемой когда делал сайт для турагенства. Джанго не видит файлы находящиеся в папке static. Не могу понять в чём проблема. Надеюсь на помощь.

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
'/Backend/function/static/',
```

)

index.html:

```
{% load static %}`
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/normalize.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/components.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/header-page.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/section-top.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/section-about.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/section-contacts.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/footer-page.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/popup.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'style.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'animate.min.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/center.css' %}">

<img class="logo__img" src="{% static 'img/common/logo.png' %}" alt="" width="127" height="21">
<img src="{% static 'img\common\tour.jpg' %}">
<img src="{% static 'img/section-about/bg.jpg' %}" alt="" class="section-about__img">

<script src="{% static 'js/myLib.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/header.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/popup.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/scrollTo.js' %}"></script>
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from something.views import *
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('form/', include('form.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
   urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: делали manage.py collectstatic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как делал я:

файл **settings.py**

```
...
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
]
```

файл **urls.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),                  
    path('', include('main.urls')),                 
    path('services/', include('resources.urls')),   
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Попробуйте у себя применить вышеуказанный код.